# How can I debug gulp-data?

Tags: gulp

I am trying to pass data to another plugin using gulp-data, but it's not working. I'd like to see what gulp-data is inserting in the stream. How can I do this?

Comment: When downvoting, please leave comment as to why you find this question not useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an ugly but simple solution for debugging gulp-data:

```
var through = require('through2');

gulp.src(yourGlob)
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(data(function(){return envAndArgs}))
    .pipe(through.obj(function(file,enc,cb){console.log('file.data:'+JSON.stringify(file.data,null,2))}));
```